# Add Seeds file after Dokku build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dokku, dokku-alt

I am using [dokku-alot](https://github.com/dokku-alt/dokku-alt) to deploy my Rails 4 app to my staging server and everything is working just swell.

One requirement I have with my current project is in regards to seed file data.  I've had to keep my `seeds.rb` file out of version control because of sensitive information.  However, I can't figure out how to add the `seeds.rb` file into the container after a build.

I've tried `ssh root@myhost ap_name` which gets me into the VM but even if I scp the files into there, the container doesn't see them.  How can I drop a few files where my rails code is in the docker image?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good solution to this? In the same boat.

Comment: I ended up adding the seeds file to VC, pushing up locally and then resetting head.  Not a great solution but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much information is in your `seeds.rb` file, you could use [environmental variables](https://github.com/dokku-alt/dokku-alt#environment-variable-management). This the solution I ended up using.

You basically set the variable: `config:set my-app SECRET=whateversupersecretinfo`. Then in your code, you can extract that app variable by using `ENV['SECRET']`. (This works pretty much the [same in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)) Not sure if that would solve your use case, but leaving this answer here for posterity.

*subnote:* In Node.js you can extract these variables like `process.env.SECRET`